# Android Studio Logcat not showing anything

Tags: logging, android-studio

Recently, the logcat on android studio has stopped showing anything at all. I don't mean a "Nothing To Show" message, it just won't show anything. I have tried restarting the logcat, clearing the cache, changing the filter settings, and using the command line with `adb logcat`. How should i fix this?

**EDIT**: I have been using logcat without issues until now.

Comment: Try with command line method using `adb logcat`.

Comment: i have, will clarify that in my question

Comment: nothing, it just says "waiting for device"

Comment: Allow USB debugging in Android phone developer mode. Use `adb devices` and accept the keys in phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ubuntu OS:

- Update the adb packages in the Android Studio terminal
- Then do `adb logcat` in Android Studio terminal
- When the message for "waiting for device" appears,
  do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Android Studio terminal
- Then close emulator if it’s open
- Then restart the emulator again

Answer (score 0):

Got to Android Studio:

- Open edit configuration, on your top right hand corner
- Click on the Miscellaneous tab
- Tick "Show logcat automatically" box.

Done.